# check if a string has four consecutive letters in ascending or descending order

Tags: java, regex, string, automata

Good day stack overflow.

I'm a noob in using regex and here is my problem - I need to check a password if it contains 4 consecutive characters. so far what I have just covered is regarding the digits. Here is my regex:

ascending digits - ^.*?(?:0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789).*$

descending digits - ^.*?(?:9876|8765|7654|6543|5432|4321|3210).*$

This works only for the digits. I know this is already an overkill in regex so I dont want to do it with the letters. It will be waaay too overkill if I do that.

abcdblah //true because of abcd

helobcde //true because of bcde

dcbablah //true beacause of dcba

heloedcb //true because of edcb

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks stackoverflow.

Comment: Why insist on a regex, when the problem is much easier to solve without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an idea that doesn't use regex:
all characters have an ansi value and usually consecutive. so abcd should have let's say the following ansi values:64,65,66,67

pseudocode:

```
for (i=string.start;i<string.end-4;i++) {
   check=string.substring(i,4);
   c1=check.substring(0,1);
   c2=check.substring(1,1);
   c3=check.substring(2,1);
   c4=check.substring(3,1);
   if (c1.ansival==c2.ansival+1 && c2.ansival==c3.ansival+1 && c3.ansival==c4.ansival+1) {
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```

also repeat in reverse order (c1.ansival+1==c2.ansival) for descending order

Comment: Instead of substring you can use `charAt`.

Comment: yeah it was just a quick and dirty javascript-like pseudocode, charat would be faster

Answer (score 7):

The answer is simple: don't use regexes.

Use this approach:

- iterate over each letter (of course, skip the last tree letters)

  - iterate over the next three letters and check for ascending order

    - if they all were ascending return true.
  - iterate over the next three letters and check for descending order

    - if they all were descending return false.
- return false

In code, this would look like this (untested code):

```
public boolean checkForAscendingOrDescendingPart(String txt, int l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= txt.length() - l; ++i)
    {
        boolean success = true;
        char c = txt.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 1; j < l; ++j)
        {
            if (((char) c + j) != txt.charAt(i + j))
            {
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (success) return true;

        success = true;

        for (int j = 1; j < l; ++j)
        {
            if (((char) c - j) != txt.charAt(i + j))
            {
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (success) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Good luck!
StackOverflow :)

Comment: This will probably be more efficient than the regex since it only has to iterate the strign once as opposed to the more complex logic that regex would have to perform. Especially when you consider that for most positions in the string the next character would not be successive so you only have to check one character instead of 3.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to solve this using regexes apart from the "overkill" solution of listing each of the possible sequences you want to match.  Regexes are not expressive enough to offer a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution. It uses only a single loop.

Keep in mind that you'll need more logic if you want to constrain it to pure ASCII.

```
static boolean isWeak(String pass) {
  Character prev = null;
  Boolean asc = null;
  int streak = 0;
  for (char c : pass.toCharArray()) {
    if (prev != null) {
      switch (c - prev) {
      case -1:
        if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(asc)) streak++;
        else { asc = false; streak = 2; }
        break;
      case 1:
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(asc)) streak++;
        else { asc = true; streak = 2; }
        break;
      default: asc = null; streak = 0;
      }
      if (streak == 4) return true;
    }
    prev = c;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

```
String s = "aba";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (!(Character.isLetter(c1) && Character.isLetter(c2))) {
            //reject
    } 
    if ((int)s.charAt(i) > (int)s.charAt(i + 1))) {
        //reject
    }
```

}

for s the if statement would be true so you could reject it. If s was abc then the if statement would never be true.

The code above using the `>` checks for ascending order. Use `<` for descending order

Comment: The criterion is actually stronger than just ascending/descending. It must be a neighboring letter, and we're checking for existence of such a sequence, not whether the string as a whole complies.